# Do you need a realtime operating system in order to ensure your program is never taken off the CPU?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, real-time, thread-priority

If I were to write a program and I wanted to be guaranteed that the program never sees an instance where, after it is running, it gets kicked off of the cpu until program termination, would I need an RTOS or is there a way to have such an experience guranteed on a regular linux os.

**Example:**
Lets say we a running a headless Linux machine and running a program as user or root (eg reading SPI data from a sensor, listening for http requests) and there is reason to believe there is almost almost no other interaction with the machine aside from the single standalone script running.

If I wanted to ensure that my process running never gets taken off my cpu even for a moment such that I never miss valuable sensor information or incoming http requests, does this warrant a real-time operating system to keep this guarantee?

- are process priorities of programs ran by the user / root enough of a priority to not get kicked off?
- is a realtime os needed to guarantee our program never witnesses a moment when it is kicked off of the cpu?

I know that Real Time OS are needed for guarantees on hard limits and hard deadlines of events. I also know that on a regular operating system it is up to the OS to decide priority and scheduling.

if this is in the wrong stack let me know.

Comment: There are some ways fullfil your demand. For example, if you want to read HTTP response without any interruption, maybe DPDK or XDP is good for you.

Comment: im speaking more generally about the possibility of a non realtime os to have a guarantee that a program invoked in user space can stay on the cpu

Comment: In general, if you ran an app 'normally'on a straightforward desktop OS like linux or Windows, you would not miss SPI/network I/O completions.  How is your app different?

Comment: Why would your app need CPU if it is waiting for SPI/network?  Why would it be 'kicked off'?  If the number of ready threads is less than the number of cores, there would be no shortage of CPU, so no preemptions.  I don't understand your issue:(

Comment: @MartinJames if im running a program that is processing or logging the data coming in from SPI and I want to ensure that my program never ever leaves the CPU until I tell it to do I need an RTOS.  Essentially the question is about 'Do you need an RTOS to ensure a program invoked in user space never gets off the cpu'

Comment: 'Do you need an RTOS to ensure a program invoked in user space never gets off the cpu', not really, no.  If that is truly what you must have, (and I'm far from convinced that's the case), you need no OS at all or, at least, a non-preemptive disk 'OS' like prehistoric MSDOS.

Comment: @MartinJames you can pin a process to a CPU core and with a little bit of luck your full-featured OS won't ever touch it. Just avoid making any syscalls from that thread. There are successfully deployed high-frequency trading solutions running an almost unpatched Linux (with a user-space Ethernet, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to act on sensor readings in a constant time frame? How complicated this action should be? If all you need is to never miss a reading and you're ok with buffering them - just add a microcontroller or an FPGA in between your non-realtime device and a sensor.

Also, you can ensure some soft real time constraints even with an unpatched Linux. You can pin a process to a CPU and avoid using any syscalls in it - spin and poll instead, at 100% CPU utilisation, and then it's likely kernel will never touch it. Make sure the process binary and all the dynamic libraries (if any) are on a RAM disk (to avoid paging) and disable swap.

Comment: i will look more into pinning a process to the CPU that could be key.

In the case of the question Im posing Im curious if it is possible to configure an invocation of  program such that you are  guaranteed that it never gets booted from the CPU so you can continue reading valuable data and not miss important reads on a regular OS.  I see that adding a micro controller inbetween is valuable and In a way more akin to a real time system

Comment: @KevinCrum 'so you can continue reading valuable data and not miss important reads on a regular OS' ??  That is what interrupts, drivers, buffers, queues and threads are for.  You do not need a user process/thread to be 'always on the CPU' in order to handle I/O reliably.  Modern preemptive kernels exist primariy in to get good I/O performance.  Maybe I still do not understand your requirement:(:

Comment: thanks martin for your time and thoughts. I suppose my examples Im posing are getting in the way of the question about ensuring a process stays on the cpu through the duration of the program's invocation.

Comment: @MartinJames some sensors won't give you continuous readings without getting requests first. And those requests need to be sent at stable time intervals. Think of devices like rotational encoders, IMUs, etc. You cannot just sit there and wait for them to fill your DMA buffers, you have to interact in a more involved way.

Comment: Also, in general, real time systems should not rely on interrupts and preemptive multi-tasking if you need a guaranteed response time. For example, in high frequency trading systems it's common to use user-space Ethernet, polling at a 100% CPU utilisation instead of waiting for an interrupt. This removes the unpredictable cost of context switching and pretty much guarantees that once a byte is there you'll know immediately and will be able to act on it immediately. Where microseconds or even nanoseconds count it's priceseless.

Comment: @SK-logic what does such polling do to memory bandwidth available to the rest of the app?

Comment: @MartinJames, "the rest of the app" is not supposed to do anything when you're polling. A real-time system must do one thing at a time, at dedicated time slices. E.g., you spend 5 microseconds polling UART and then 10 microseconds acting on what you received (no matter if you did not receive anything, still spend 10 microseconds), then 5 microseconds initiating an SPI transaction / polling SPI DMA, then 10 more microseconds doing something with that data, and so on.